# Updating Tomcat LIb Folder

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

i have an application developed by using Jersey Plugin and deployed on Tomact 7 .
i have to export all the jars used in the project to the lib/ folder of Tomact .. but i dont want to..
is it possible to deploy my app without exporting jars to Tomcat lib folder . If Yes , then How ?

https://t1.ap01.aws.af.cm/rest/person

this is my app link and it gives following error if lib/ are not exported:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available

type Status report

message Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need the required jars in the lib folder, whether you package them up using ant or Maven - you always need the jars in the lib folder.  The error you are seeing there is the application cannot find the Jersey jars.

The jars should be part of the war when it gets built.

Comment: You say "the jars should be part of the WAR" - Preetam says "I have to export all the jars used in the project to the lib folder of Tomcat". That's a significant difference! Can these libraries in fact be packed into the WAR, or do they need to be added to the Tomcat classpath?

Comment: Generally speaking my understanding is it's much better to package the libs into the war rather than into the Tomcat classpath.  The reason for this is you can create classloading issues by putting them into the Tomcat classpath further down the line.  Although I'm more than happy to here an alternative if this isn't suitable :).

Comment: I strongly agree that putting things in the WAR is better, for a number of reasons. However, what i don't know is whether that's *possible* in this case. There are times when certain libraries have to be on the container classpath. Generally, implementations of APIs where the implementation loader is on the container classpath, and therefore is unable to see classes loaded from the application classpath. XML parsers are a classic example, and i've seen JAX-WS client libraries have the same problem. You can't just put them in the WAR, they have to go in the container's lib directory. Sadly.

Comment: I've never had issues related to libraries that HAD to go in the container's lib, fortunately! I think the original purpose of that folder was to contain "shared" libraries (used by more than 1 web app) and it's funny how with every version of Tomcat they've removed and refactored those folders (there were common/lib and shared/lib... now there's only lib)

Comment: I always feel "sharing" libraries across different web apps is a bit dangerous anyway as if one app suddenly uses a different version of the library you have to refactor to then include it in the .war classpath.  To coin a phrase, disk space is cheap - I'd rather not have the dependency and just have the same library in two war files.