# updating jars in lib of tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, jersey

i have an application developed by using Jersey Plugin and deployed on Tomact 7 . i have to export all the jars used in the project to the lib/ folder of Tomact .. but i dont want to.. is it possible to deploy my app without exporting jars to Tomcat lib folder . If Yes , then How ?

I have heard of using maven or classpath but i hv hosted my app in appfog so i dont control the servers.

https://t1.ap01.aws.af.cm/rest/person

this is my app link and it gives following error if lib/ are not exported:

```
HTTP Status 404 - Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available

type Status report

message Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet Jersey REST Service is not available) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

***Sorry for reposting the question : This is my old account jst got access back..plz answer here no more able to access the [Updating Tomcat LIb Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647991/updating-tomcat-lib-folder) this question using the account by which i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, place all the required jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web app and they'll be accessible to the Tomcat.

In this way your web app contains all the required jars without the need of relying on jars in the Tomcat lib folder that might or might not be available.